# How to deploy a Symfony project via Netbeans?

Tags: symfony, netbeans, ftp

I was trying to move my project to my new domain using Netbeans.
So i uploded all of my project via the option run as remote web site and 
everything seems okay but when i run it i get this error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in /home/a584949/public_html/test1/web/app_dev.php on line 3
```

and as you see it's not in production mode because i need to test my work online to get rid of the localhost

thanks for your understanding,
waiting for your answers !

Comment: what is the PHP version on the server?

Comment: can you change it to an higher version?

Comment: no i am just new in this , i brought a domain and i host it for free in 000webhost

Comment: well alright but 5.2 is quite old. PHP needs to be a minimum version of PHP 5.5.9 for Symfony 3.0 and 5.3.9 for Symfony 2.7

Comment: thanks i will try to change it then